# Why have unary_function, binary_function been removed from C++11?

Tags: c++, c++11, stl, functor, unary-function

I found that `binary_function` is removed from C++11. I am wondering why.

C++98:

```
template <class T> struct less : binary_function <T,T,bool> {
  bool operator() (const T& x, const T& y) const {return x<y;}
};
```

C++11:

```
template <class T> struct less {
  bool operator() (const T& x, const T& y) const {return x<y;}
  typedef T first_argument_type;
  typedef T second_argument_type;
  typedef bool result_type;
};
```

**MODIFIED**----------------------------------------------------------------------------

```
template<class arg,class result>
struct unary_function
{
       typedef arg argument_type;
       typedef result result_type;
};
```

For example, if we want to write our adapter for function even in C++98,

```
template <class T> struct even : unary_function <T,bool> {
  bool operator() (const T& x) const {return 0==x%2;}
};

find_if(bgn,end,even<int>()); //find even number

//adapter
template<typename adaptableFunction >
class unary_negate
{
   private:
       adaptableFunction fun_;
   public:
       typedef adaptableFunction::argument_type argument_type;

       typedef adaptableFunction::result_type result_type;  
       unary_negate(const adaptableFunction &f):fun_(f){}

       bool operator()(const argument_type&x) 
       {
           return !fun(x);
       }
}

find_if(bgn,end, unary_negate< even<int> >(even<int>()) ); //find odd number
```

How can we improve this in C++11 without `unary_function`?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

It isn't removed, it's just deprecated in C++11. It's still part of the C++11 standard. You can still use it in your own code. It was removed in C++17 though.

It isn't used *in the standard* any more because requiring implementations to derive from `binary_function` is over-specification.

Users should not care whether `less` derives from `binary_function`, they only need to care that it defines `first_argument_type`, `second_argument_type` and `result_type`. It should be up to the implementation how it provides those typedefs.

Forcing the implementation to derive from a specific type means that users might start relying on that derivation, which makes no sense and is not useful.

**Edit**

> How can we improve this in c++11 without unary_function?

You don't need it.

```
template<typename adaptableFunction>
class unary_negate
{
   private:
       adaptableFunction fun_;
   public:
       unary_negate(const adaptableFunction& f):fun_(f){}

       template<typename T>
           auto operator()(const T& x)  -> decltype(!fun_(x))
           {
               return !fun_(x);
           }
}
```

In fact you can do even better, see [`not_fn`: a generalized negator](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3800.html)

Answer (score 22):

With variadic templates, a lot of general function composing can be expressed much more simply and consistently, so all of the old cruft is no longer necessary:

**Do use:**

- `std::function`
- `std::bind`
- `std::mem_fn`
- `std::result_of`
- lambdas

**Don't use:**

- `std::unary_function`, `std::binary_function`
- `std::mem_fun`
- `std::bind1st`, `std::bind2nd`

Comment: binary_function <T,T,bool> can simplify our work and make code more consistent, right?

Comment: @camino: Can it, though?

Comment: without it we need define  typedef T first_argument_type;.... , maybe we will forgot something

Comment: @camino: Do we though? Why not use the existing `std::function::first_argument_type`?

Comment: so less<T> in c++11 define  first_argument_type,second_argument_type,result_type is only to be compatible with c++98, right?

Comment: @camino: Wait, `less<T>` doesn't define it, but `std::function` defines it for one- and two-argument specializations. But you don't generally need those types when you have arbitrary binding facilities available anyway...

Comment: @KerrekSB, `less<T>` does define them (to be compatible with C++98), `less<void>` doesn't

Comment: FYIW std::function::first_argument_type seems also to be deprecated in C++17
http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function

Comment: @bergercookie: What is "FYIW"?!

Comment: @KerrekSB A typo (FWIW), probably.