# C++: Why are function object base classes, adaptors and binders deprecated(C++11) and removed(C++17)?

Tags: c++, c++11, c++17, functor, function-object

Why are function object base classes (unary_function, binary_function), adaptors (pointer_to_unary_function, pointer_to_binary_function, ...) and binders(binder1st, binder2nd, ...) deprecated(C++11) and removed(C++17) ?

Comment: [`std::function`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function) and [closures](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda) (lambda expresions) cover pretty much all your bases.

Comment: related/dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22386882/why-have-unary-function-binary-function-been-removed-from-c11.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33114656/replacement-for-binary-function

Comment: Thanks @Francois for the answer and thanks NathanOliver for pointing other question